# show $P(B^c\mid A) < P(B^c)$

Tags: probability

> If $P(B\mid A) > P(B)$, show that $P(B^c\mid A) < P(B^c)$.

I have started this problem by adding $P(B^c\mid A)$ to both sides of the given inequality.

$$P(B^c\mid A) + P(B\mid A) > P(B)+ P(B^c\mid A)$$

Not sure how to expand and solve from here.

Comment: Hint: On what you began with, note that the left-hand side equals $1$, and so you know that $$1 > P(B) + P(B^c\mid A)$$ and also that $$1 = P(B) + P(B^c).$$ Does this suggest anything?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the law of complements: $$\mathsf P(B\mid A) > \mathsf P(B) \\ \Updownarrow \\ 1 - \mathsf P(B'\mid A) > 1 - \mathsf P(B') \\ \Updownarrow \\ \vdots$$